# Matching nested groups with named backreference

Tags: c#, regex

I need to use a multiline regex to extract part of a text, but I also have to allow those parts to be nested.

Here's an example of my scenario:

```
<!--BEGIN DELIMITER(A)-->
    sample text
    <!--BEGIN DELIMITER(B)-->
        another sample text
    <!--END DELIMITER(B)-->
<!--END DELIMITER(A)-->
```

The expected result would be to extract both blocks, including the begin/end lines as `A1` and `A2` are required for other things.

What happens is that I only get one match, which is the outer group.

Here's my regex:

```
<!--BEGIN DELIMITER\((?<expr>(\w+))\)-->(?<content>([\s\S]*?))<!--END DELIMITER\((\k<expr>.*)\)-->
```

Here's a [regex101.com link](https://regex101.com/r/YxLfzu/2) for a quick visual reference.

Any idea on how to match both groups?

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/4lep7o/1). Just wrap with a lookahead and a capturing group.

Comment: That is not regular. Thus you can't use **Regular** Expressions to match this. It's effectively a different ["HTML syntax", as far as parsing goes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1045510).

Comment: You can however build a more sophisticated parser that uses RegEx just for the regular parts (detecting the start and end "tags"), and then build a tree out of it. Then you can select the contents however you want.

Comment: @Kroltan, you could, i suppose. Remember that the RegEx engine of .NET supports balancing groups...

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, but it gets surprisingly messy surprisingly fast, and isn't perfect either. When in the future you want to extend the pattern, it's not going to be any fun.

Comment: This link might help you : http://www.rexegg.com/regex-cookbook.html#captureparen2

Comment: @Kroltan, about that i fully agree with you :)